jdk8 in vscode 32bit
I have a 32-bit Windows 10 system that I want to write and run Java code on, but in vscode it says that you need jdk above 17 and the rest of the compilers are 64-bit, what should I do to fix this problem?

Isn't the last 32bit Windows JDK Java 8?

Use a 64-bit operating system?

Java 8 is the last 32 bit Windows JDK distributed by Oracle or the OpenJDK team.  But you can get 32 bit Windows distros for later versions of Java from 3rd party vendors.  For example, Azul.  But yea, why are you running a 32 bit Windows, in 2024?

Requires jdk17 and above to activate the Java Language Server.
